# Loop through reduce (groupBy) results

Tags: javascript

I am using reduce to groupby objects using the following method

```
var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
    }, {});
};
```

and I get the following results:

```
var myGroupByObject = {021426003227: Array(19), 021426000016: Array(5), 021426820000: Array(2), 02146004016: Array(2), 023426840074: Array(1), …}
```

I can access an element like this

```
s['021426003227']
```

But I would like to loop through the groupByObject to get the values. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object.keys(myGroupByObject).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  myGroupByObject[key].forEach((object) => {
    console.log(object);
  });
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't as useful.  Consider adding a description / explanation or commenting your code to make it clear what you've done.

Comment: Also, OP is specifically using non-fat-arrow (as in not ES6), whereas your answer is ES6.  It's worth pointing _that_ out as well in your answer, to make it clear to future visitors.